# Compile & Package EXT.JS app to post to web

Tags: extjs

I have created an app using EXT.js 5.0 & Sencha CMD. Everything works fine in the dev environment while I have the app watcher running, but I can't seem to package it right to post to the web. (I am posting to GoDaddy hosted site in case that matters.)

I ran 'sencha app build' & it created a production folder but when I upload it to the web (or open index in chrome) it is just a blank page. Please let me know what steps I need to take to compile/package this app for production. I can't find any instructions on this & I am very confused.

Comment: When you run your app locally in dev mode, if you check your browser's console, do you see any classes being loaded Synchronously ?

Comment: No, I don't think so...?